In perl, will a system call that runs in the background persist after the perl script ends
perl 5.32.1 on linux
If I do a system call that runs a command in the background, will that background process persist after the perl script ends ?  E.g.
system("rm -rf /disk/rm_this_big_dir >& /dev/null &");

Removing "/disk/rm_this_big_dir" needs to keep running, even after the perl script that ran the system call finishes.  (That's what the trailing '&' is supposed to do.)

The parent of the rm is sh, not perl. And rm obviously keeps running after sh exits. This is easy to verify by using ps. The real question is what else could kill rm. Now you enter the domain of program groups and sessions, and I'm not very familiar with them.

On my Ubuntu with Perl 5.38, it does keep running. Try with perl -e 'system("sleep 60s &");'; ps | grep sleep and you'll see your sleep process.

Yes, it will keep running. But if you logout, that may kill it. You should use nohup to ensure it keeps running after a logout or disconnection.

Yes.
It can be verified as follows:
$ perl
system "sleep 99 &"
^D
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
ljm      3410570       1  0 15:18 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 99
ljm      3410578 1100352  0 15:18 pts/1    00:00:00 grep sleep

